# How to use stackedbar chart in Web forms?

Tags: asp.net, .net, charts, webforms, stacked-chart

I have a table consisting of few data. 
[image]

I have used stacked bar chart in webform. How can i compare the below data ? I trying something like with the y axis with the Machine_name and in the x-axis of having Total, Turn_right and Turn_left.

In stacked bar chart i get something like [image] 
.

How am i able to display from the total of 9, Turn right is 2 and turn left is 2. As of the below it adds up which i am not interested. 
Note: I am getting the data from sql datasource

Comment: Use `Bar` chart type rather than `StackedBar`.  [See sample here](https://imgur.com/a/pN7tY).